# How to get completion callback from MFMailComposeViewController when it's presented by a UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiactivity

I think I can use the completion handler of the `UIActivityViewController` (haven't tested yet), but that would only give me a `BOOL` for whether the activity completed or not.  I want to be able to handle the error if there is one, as I would in `-[MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:]`.  Is there a way to be notified, without having to mess with private APIs?  Looks like `UIMailActivity` is the delegate for the mail composer that gets presented.  Any official way to do this?